# Reading data from firebase database in the background

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an app that uses `firebaserecycleradapter/view` to show data on the screen. Works very well, but I have one problem.  When I send a notification for breaking news, and when the user clicks the notification, my news app opens up, but it takes a while before the latest news is loaded.

I would like to load the data in the background in the `onMessageReceived` of the notification (which contains data also), so that when the user opens the news activity, the latest news items are already available. Code given below:

```
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
            processData(remoteMessage);
        }
        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());            
        }
}
private void processData(RemoteMessage rm){
    // This is the exact same ref and query that is used by the firebaserecycleradapter
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("all_news");
    Query q = ref.orderByChild("mStatus").equalTo(2).limitToLast(100);
    q.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // Nothing.  The idea is just to read the data upfront so that fetch appears faster
            Long count = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
            Log.d(TAG, "ProcessData Count" + count);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            // Nothing
        }
    });
}
```

`ProcessData` gets called and `onDataChanged` also gets called, so I know that the data is being read here.  But when I open the app and go to the activity using the same database reference, the activity seems to be reading the data again!!  Why is this happening?

Comment: Use Intent Services for that , It will able to call processData(remoteMessage) in background even when the app is not in foreground state.

Comment: Try blocking thread before `processData` using `CountDownLatch` or `Semaphore`

Comment: I am sorry if my question is not clear.  I am using the same firebase databasereference in two different places (one inside the Firebase Messaging Service and another inside an activity).  If I read all the data from the database reference at one place (say, inside the messaging service), should not that data be reflected in the other place (in the activity when I open it) automatically?

Answer (score 2):

After digging around some more, I found out that the `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` was reading from the cache and not from the firebase server because I had set `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);` in my Application class.
I have now removed this entire `ProcessData` function and instead called `KeepSynced(true)` on the `databasereference` path in my activity.

The app works as I expected now.

Thanks for all the responses.

Answer (score 0):

1. first you need to use data Message in FCM because when you used notification message then onMessageReceived never called when the app is in the background.
2. when onMessageReceived called then get the news id and start the intent service that downloads the news content for you. when the download is completed then create a notification in that intent service. now its up to you store the news content in DB, shared pref or pass it in pending intent with notification. I hope it will help you.

Comment: I know you have a choice to write code of downloading news content and then show notification here or create a separate Intent service that handles this scenario new one.